# After hibernate, can't turn on laptop

Tags: laptop, hibernate

I can't turn on laptop after hibernation.

Usually one of power light is glowing when laptop is plugged with adapter. Even when it is not yet turned on, the light is glowing. This time, it is not glowing.

This never happens before. Usually it is fine when I hibernate.

I try changing different adapter, replugging the battery, getting off the hard drive. But all fails. Laptop is still dead, the light is not glowing.

What is happening? Please help. Much appreciated.

Comment: What different adapter did you try? Are all adapters OEM? Getting off the hard drive? What does that mean? Please elaborate on your steps if you want good assistance.